The binomial distribution - can the IID assumption be relaxed?
I have done some reading and have re-written my question to make it a little more precise ( I hope ).
It is known from previous surveys that 50% residents oppose a policy. It is decided to contact least 300 people who oppose the policy in the hope of driving up support. This should be done at least cost.
For the sake of simplicity, residents do not change their views.
Using the binomial distribution with Theta = 0.5 and different values of N I think we could identify a target group of size N that guaranteed that:
Pr ( X >=300 ) >= 95%
I believe this would work if the population was homogenous. Here  homogenous would mean that the Theta was identically distributed across residents.
But let's assume, more realistically, that the there are two different groups of equal size in the population. Their "Theta values" are given below:
Group A :  0.75.
Group B  : 0.25
Can the binomial distribution procedure be used in the heterogenous group?
The Random Variables to compare are:
X_ho : The number of Successes in the Homogenous Group
X_he : The number of Successes in the Heterogenous Group
X_he_A, X_he_B:  The number of successes in groups A and B respectively.
X_he = X_he_A + X_he_B
Number of Trials:
N_ho =  N_he
... Number of trials in the Binomial Distribution for the homogenous and heterogenous groups
N_he = N_he_A + N_he_B
For the purposes of this question we could assume that the same number of people are contacted from each of the heterogenous populations two groups (which seems like a heroic assumption and is a concern).
As an example I'd specify :
Theta_ho = 0.5
Theta_he_A = 0.75
Theta_he_B = 0.25
My observations based on previous comments are:
E ( X_ho ) = np = N_ho * Theta_ho
E ( X_he ) = ( N_he_A * Theta_he_A ) + ( N_he_B * Theta_he_B ) = E ( X_ho )
For example if N_ho was 1000 and Group A and B are half of that, then :
X_he = 500 * 0.25 + 500 * 0.75 = 500
Therefore:
E ( X_ho ) = E ( X_he )
But in the case of the Variance:
VAR ( X_ho ) = Theta * (1- Theta)
         = 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25

VAR ( X_he ) = Var ( X_he_A ) + Var ( X_he_B )
         = ( 0.75 * 0.25 ) + (0.25 * 0.75 )

         = 0.375

VAR ( X_he ) >= VAR ( X_ho )
Therefore, it seems to me that if there is heterogeneity in the population, you should not use the binomial distribution.
What should you do in this case?  Are there any techniques to mitigate against the issue?
Thank you very much for reading especially if you made it this far.

Welcome to Cross Validated! While you're waiting for an answer, look at the mixed-model and clustered-standard-error tags on this site (or in a broader web search). Those are a couple of ways that are used to deal with the problems of intra-individual or intra-group correlations, which you rightly identify as violations of the IID assumption that underlies simpler types of analysis.

Consider plotting the probability functions.  In your example, when $n\ge 8$ the plot will be bimodal--obviously different from any Binomial distribution (and calling into question what you might mean by "give the same answer").  One related topic worth understanding is mixture distributions.

Thank you for the welcome and for both great comments. I've played around with the distributions and see that yes the two sub samples gives a bimodal distribution when you know to look for it.  The mixture info seems hard for now so I'll come back to that. It seems to me that if I could somehow average the subgroup distributions this might be tricky to do right (given differing variances). Even if I could do this then, it may be necessary to add an assumption about the mix of  subgroups A and B for it to be useful. I imagine that the real world, subgroups are not always identifiable. Thanks!

There are signs that there may be something interesting in this question, but I may have to spend some time trying to understand what it says.

It is not clear enough so please don't waste time on it and thanks for the comment. I will do some more reading and try to get more background before posting a question.  I'm now quite interested in how the central limit theorem applies to the binomial distribution. As for the question, I'll try to either fix it up at the weekend or delete it.

It looks like you might have multiple accounts.  Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge them: that will enable you to edit your post.

I will be merging my accounts shortly now that things are quieter. I thought I had accepted a useful answer but it is no longer here to view.
